# Access array from session Java

Tags: java, jsp, session, iframe, attributes

I have a `jsp` page and a `modal` page.
Snippets:

JSP:

```
arr[0][0] = "Name";
arr[0][1] = "Link";
arr[0][2] = "Pic";
arr[0][3] = "Title";
arr[0][4] = "0:42"; 
arr[0][5] = "Desc.";

arr[1][0] = "Name";
arr[1][1] = "Link";
arr[1][2] = "Pic";
arr[1][3] = "Title";
arr[1][4] = "1:28";
arr[1][5] = "Desc.";

session.setAttribute("arr", arr);

<a href="/video_ModalBox.jsp?video=<%=arr[vid][1]%>" 
onclick="openInfoBox(this.href, 'Video', 'default', 'default', 'none');
return false";><img src="<%=arr[vid][2]%>" alt="Play Video" border="0"></a>
```

Modal:

```
<iframe class="videoContainer" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" id="videoHolder" 
src="/player.jsp?title="<%=session.getAttribute("arr[i][3]")%>
&image"<%=session.getAttribute("arr[i][2]")%>"
&Description"<%=session.getAttribute("arr[i][5]")%>" 
allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

The problem is that it doesn't access the data. It is all `null`.
Do I need to add anything else to pass the data in the `session`? Is it possible that I need to include the `session` in the `modal`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking honestly scriptlets should not be used in 2017. Even JSP usage itself is often considered as deprecated today.

Try this:

```
<%=((String[][])session.getAttribute("arr"))[i][3]%>
```

It worked for me.

Comment: @Nik, sorry, forgot to cast from `Object` to `String[][]`.

After adding the type casting it definitely works(I've tested the snippet).

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See Servlet:

```
String[] host = {"Name","Host"};
session.setAttribute("session", host);
request.getRequestDispatcher(HOME).forward(request, response);
```

JSP:

```
${session[0]} return "Name"
${session[1]} return "Host"
```